# ResizeObserver on iframe body behaves differently on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, iframe, webapi, mutation-observers

I'm trying to use ResizeObserver in order to listen for changes on the height of a document body and consequently adapt the size of the iframe which contains it.

Everything seems to work fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox, where resize events do not seem to trigger the observer callback in the right way.

This is the observer code, which updates the container height on every content size change:

```
const iframeElement = document.getElementById("container");
const iframeContent = iframeElement.contentWindow.document.body;

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        iframeElement.style.height = `${entry.target.scrollHeight}px`;
    });
});
resizeObserver.observe(iframeContent);
```

Here is a simple JSFiddle that clearly shows what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/ujxkre85/.

The containing iframe should adapt to the height of its content while this gets incremented. As you can see, it works fine on Chrome, but almost nothing happens running it on Firefox.

Is there something I'm not getting about the API or is Firefox missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: If you actually debug the code and DOM while it runs you will see that iframe's body element is not modified at all. There's probably a bug in Firefox that makes `content` point to some detached node. Don't use it, just spell iframeElement.contentDocument.body fully each time. P.S. There's probably another bug with ResizeObserver in Firefox - try using IntersectionObserver with a 1px element at the end of iframe.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the comment. You're right about the body not getting modified, I didn't notice it, I'm updating the fiddle. Anyway, this is not an issue with my actual code. I'm more concerned about the behavior of the observer, do you think it's a Firefox bug? I already have a working solution which makes use of MutationObserver, but using ResizeObserver felt way more appropriate in this situation. So sad.

Comment: For reference: here is a bug report for Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1689099

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a bug that is described here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1689099

> ResizeObserver callback doesn't reliably fire, when observing an element in an iframe subdocument (with the observer registered in outer document)

So probably using MutationObserver is a best option.

Comment: Thank you! I filed that bug shortly after opening this thread, sadly there doesn't seem to be much activity going on about it.